# Retrieve column value with eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I want to retrieve column value with eloquent.

In mysql statement,

```
SELECT 'click_count' WHERE 'uri' = 'something'
```

In eloquent ???

Comment: Have you had a model set?

Comment: yes... i wrote like $click_count = Visitor::where('uri', '/posts/1')->first('click_count'); but i got can't convert to int error message.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `click_count` column already exists in your database

If you need a single row (this will return the value):

```
$post = Visitor::where('uri', 'something')->first()->click_count;
```

If you need to select multiple rows (this will return a `collection`):

```
$post = Visitor::where('uri', 'something')->get()->pluck('click_count');
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass an array of the columns you want back to use first that way.

```php
$post = Visitor::where('uri', '/posts/1')->first(['click_count']);
```

Then `$post['click_count']` would be your value.

You can just get the count back in a variable using something like.

```php
$click_count = Visitor::where('uri', '/posts/1')->pluck('click_count')->first();
```